# Error while trying to create react app using npx create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodes, node-modules, npx

I'm getting the following error while trying to create a react app using npx. What am I doing wrong and how do I resolve it?

**Node js error log file**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
```

**main error:**

```
203 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})
204 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
204 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
204 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
204 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: ia32
205 verbose type body-timeout
206 verbose stack FetchError: Response timeout while trying to fetch http://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2fparser (over 30000ms)
206 verbose stack     at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:189:16)
206 verbose stack     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
206 verbose stack     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
207 verbose cwd E:\Reactjs\my-app
208 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
209 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "--save-exact" "--loglevel" "error" "react" "react-dom" "react-scripts" "cra-template"
210 verbose node v12.16.2
211 verbose npm  v6.14.4
212 error Response timeout while trying to fetch http://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2fparser (over 30000ms)
213 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

[image: See image1]

[image: See image2]

Comment: The first error image shows a bad JSON file - I'm not sure which file.  The more detailed log file mentioned in that screenshot may contain more useful info.  The 212 error in your text looks like a temporary or local network/server issue.  That URL seems reachable now for me.

Comment: When possible, it is preferable to include all errors and console logs as plain text in your question, images are nice but not searchable. What have you tried doing to rectify the errors?

Comment: Strange that it tries to compile fsevents (which is a macOS specific lib) on Windows. It shouldn't do that in the first place and that it does indicates a configuration problem.